# Pandas - rolling up rows to fill in missing data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an issue that I'm hoping has a relatively simple solution. I have a dataframe with multiple records per unique contact (see "name" below). I'm trying to GroupBy the name and roll up values where they are missing.

```
   name   id            email
0   bob  5.0              NaN
1   bob  NaN     test@foo.com
2  bill  3.0              NaN
3  bill  NaN  something@a.com
```

The expected output would be:

```
   name   id            email
0   bob  5.0     test@foo.com  
1  bill  3.0     something@a.com
```

I've tried Pivoting and Re-pivoting a few different ways to no avail. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `groupby.first()`:

```
df.groupby('name')[['id', 'email']].first()

#        id           email
#name       
#bill   3.0 something@a.com
#bob    5.0    test@foo.com
```

Also check the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.19.2/pandas/core/groupby.py#L108-L123)(according to which it takes the first non-null value) here if you are interested.

Comment: df.groupby('name', as_index=False).first()

Comment: @Boud The simplicity of that makes what I was trying seem so silly.

Comment: @Mitch hehe, I've been through bfill ffill combinations also in the past (yes I can read in your mind)

Comment: @Boud Good call. I'll leave it as a helpful comment.

Comment: @Boud _What_, how did you know :)

Comment: @Psidom Sure. Actually as_index=False is the ignored one in most groupby examples, where it actually avoid remerging / reassigning stuff with the original df

Comment: Very cool, thank you. The doc really doesn't have much info on this. Is there anything I should keep in mind when using this method?

Comment: Yeah. The doc is quite vague about the usage of this method. But if you look at the definition of the first method. `_first_compat`, it's actually pretty simple and straight forward. So I guess you don't have to be too cautious, maybe just keep in mind how it is defined. :)